# Loading a specific div from a page using .ajax

Tags: jquery

I need to load the contents of a div residing on a page inside my website into a div that is shown in Fancybox. Basically, I'm loading a reservation form into a div and showing the whole thing with fancybox. I can't use the .load() function because it strips out all the script tags that validate the form, etc. I'm trying to use the .ajax() function to grab all the html including script tags and other jquery references.

Here's a snipit of what I'm working with:

```
$.ajax({
url: eventUrl,
dataType: 'html',
success: function(data) {           
var include = $(data).filter($('#bookingFormWrapper'))
alert(include);                 
}
});
```

The Ajax call here is using a variable to get the url of the page where the detail lives. I need to add the contents of #bookingFormWrapper to a div called #detailView. I'm using alert for testing purposes only. I can't seem to grab just the contents of #bookingFormWrapper. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is `$data()` a typo? There's no `$data()` function in your script. Shouldn't it be `$(data).filter(...)` instead?

Comment: Yes, sorry! When I use $(data).filter() I get [object], [object] back in the alert. Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: That's to be expected. jquery returns objects. try `console.log(include)` instead of alert and look at at the Firebug console (assuming you've got Firebug installed). You'll see the element you wanted, wrapped in jquery stuff.

Answer (score 1):

it's easier if you use .load, like ...
`$("#detailview").load(eventUrl + " #bookingFormWrapper")`

Comment: This does work but I loose all the script tags in the process. I need to keep the script tags that are part of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$('#bookingFormWrapper').innerHtml()` or `$('#bookingFormWrapper').html()`  ?